# How to change one movieclip's alpha if a different movieclip has triggered a mouse over event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, adobe, navigation

I have a movie clip (let's call it mc_A for identification purposes) that rolls down on a mouse over event and rolls back up on a mouse out event. I have a separate movie clip (mc_B) that I want to make invisible when mc_A is rolled up. Then fade in when mc_A's mouse over event is triggered.

This is the code I have so far, that is, as far as the button 'sliding itself down' on mouse over.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

/************** Slide Menu **************/
var invisible_menu : Number = menu_mc.y;
var visible_menu : Number = 12;

menu_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,showMenu);
menu_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,hideMenu);

function showMenu(event:MouseEvent) :void{
    TweenLite.to(menu_mc, .15, {y:visible_menu,ease:Linear.easeNone});
}

function hideMenu(event:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(menu_mc, .15, {y:invisible_menu,ease:Linear.easeNone});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.  I am presuming in the code below that menu_mc is the mc_a you are referring to.

```
function showMenu(event:MouseEvent) :void
{
    TweenLite.to(mc_b, .15, {alpha:1,ease:Linear.easeNone});
    TweenLite.to(menu_mc, .15, {y:visible_menu,ease:Linear.easeNone});
}


function hideMenu(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenLite.to(mc_b, .15, {alpha:0,ease:Linear.easeNone});
    TweenLite.to(menu_mc, .15, {y:invisible_menu,ease:Linear.easeNone});
}
```

also, not sure what you're doing with the line:

```
light_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.
```

but that is incomplete.  Perhaps just a bad copy and paste?

and if you change your variable instantiation to:

```
var invisible_menu : Number = menu_mc.y;
var visible_menu : Number = invisible_menu + 12;
```

then you can adjust the location of your menu and still have it drop down the same distance without having to adjust the visible_menu variable again.

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot to delete that one line. It was indeed a bad copy & paste. Thank you for catching that! mc_A that I am referring to in my OP is the sliding button itself, and mc_B is the movie clip that I want to change the alpha of. mc_A I lumped together in my post as both the invisible and visible menu.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Cheers!